# Guessing XOR secret key knowing some part of it

Tags: python, encryption, xor, secret-key

I'm trying to guess the secret key to decrypt a message using Python 3. I know the message is going to be something like: `crypto{1XXXXXX}` where the XXXXXXX is the unknown part of the message.
The encrypt message is: `'0e0b213f26041e480b26217f27342e175d0e070a3c5b103e2526217f27342e175d0e077e263451150104'` and I have the following code:

```
from pwn import xor

flkey=bytes.fromhex('0e0b213f26041e480b26217f27342e175d0e070a3c5b103e2526217f27342e175d0e077e263451150104')

print(flkey)

y = xor(flkey, "crypto{1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}")

print(y)

xor(flkey, y)
```

My question is, how can I find the rest of the message knowing only some part of it? I'm quite new in this topic related to XOR.

EDIT: when I print(y) I obtain:

```
b'crypto{1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}'
```

So i guess the length of between the brackets is 34.

Comment: What's the length of the key?

Comment: That's a problem because I don't know, however, when I XOR the encrypt message (len=84) with ```"crypto{1}"``` I get a message with len=42, so half of the encrypt message.

Comment: Your encrypted message is 42 bytes long. 84 is the hex-encoded length.

Comment: I see and can this help to obtain the key length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weak point of the XOR operation in cryptography is that `A XOR B XOR A = B`. So when you know the part of the plaintext message `M` for the corresponding encrypted message `C`, you immediately obtain that part of the key as `K = M XOR C`.

In particular:

```
 >>> cypher = bytes.fromhex('0e0b213f26041e480b26217f27342e175d0e070a3c5b103e2526217f27342e175d0e077e263451150104')
 >>> plaintext = b'crypto{1'
 >>> key = ''.join(chr(c ^ m) for c, m in zip(cypher, plaintext))
 >>> key
 'myXORkey'
```

The chances are high that this is the entire key (it actually is, which is left as an exercise). This string will repeat as many times as needed to match the plain text length.

Suppose now, that this was not the entire key. We know, however, that the key repeats in a loop, so that part we alreaydy know, `myXORkey`, will be reused somewhere later. We can start applying it to various places in the cypher and see when it starts making sense. That way we know the key length and parts of the messages. There are few ways from here, the most simple is, because we know some parts of the plaintext, we can find the missing part by sense and from there find the remaining part of the key.

The following properties may help:

- the key is sufficiently short
- the key makes some sense
- you know the language the plain text is written in

If the key is as long as the message, is truly random, and used only once, the cypher cannot be broken (See [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)).

In a generic case when the plaintext or/and the key length is unknown, there is more sophisticated method based on the [Hamming distance and transposition](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6) (The method was first discovered in 19th century by Friedrich Kasiski to analyze the [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).

Comment: I understand but the plaintext in the code wouldn't be ```b'crypto{1xxxxxx}'```? where xxxxxx is unknown. I mean, there is some part left as ```'myXORkey'``` is not the entire key as I have checked.

Comment: @Raúl when the XOR / Vigenère key is shorter than the message (which it usually is), it's just repeated in a loop to the message length. It will be `myXORkeymyXORkeymy...`. If the key is as long as the message, it's impossible to crack without extra information (see [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)).

Comment: I see but for example if I add ```b'crypto{1bu'``` I get ```'myXORkeyis'``` could it be maybe the continuation of the key. How do you know ```'myXORkey'``` is the correct solution? Couldn't it be longer? And what extra information would be needed for the example you told me?

Comment: For example, if I "complete" the plain text with ```"crypto{1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}"``` I get the key is not repeated so I think that is the length of the plain text, I just need to guess the xxxxx. I edited my question code so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you, how can I apply the part we know to different parts of the cypher?

Comment: @Raúl you try different offsets of the cypher and apply the key to the corresponding substring.

Comment: Thank you and lastly how can I offset the cypher using python? I'm not used to work with python and I only know the basics :/ Thank you

Comment: @Raúl `cypher[offset:offset+length]`.

Comment: Thank you! I finally got the key! I just did that and I found the offset was 0, so it was simpler than we thought. Thank you so much, I was really stuck with this.